# Lightning avatar component has error

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I use `lightning:avatar` component in my employee card. And found one error when try filtering list of employees.
After filtering my list of employees i set final list in component atribute which using in `aura:iteration`. When Aura try rerendering my employee card in `component.set` occur aura exception in `lightning:avatar` component:

> `src` attribute for lightning:avatar has to have a non-empty value.

But all sections with avatar component not rendering if i not have path to photo.

I resolved this problem using expression in src atribute `{! v.pathToPhoto ? v.pathToPhoto : 'foo' }`. But this way isn't true :(

How to fix this error another way?

P.S. I don't write here code snippets because this components very big.

Comment: Please post your component code so we can see the problem

Comment: My component is big and this problem needs to show deeply...